# Datetime - figuring out how long until a specified time

Tags: python, datetime

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'hours'
```

```
        previous = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(hours=24)

        if not find_user:
            await self.client.boosts.insert_one(
                {"userID": ctx.author.id, "boost_type": random_boost_type,
                 "boost_amount": round(random_boost_value, 2),
                 "boost_time_given": datetime.datetime.utcnow()})
        elif find_user:
            if find_user["boost_time_given"] > previous:
                embed = await embedHelper.error_embed(self.client, "You have already ran this command in the last 24 hours!")
                embed.description = f"`You must wait {find_user['boost_time_given'] - datetime.timedelta(hours=24).hours}`"
                return await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Hey guys. Currently trying to make the bottom embed send and display how many hours left until `find_user["boost_time_given"] < previous`

However, datetime.timedelta has no attribute hours?

Don't suppose anybody knows how I can display the hours left?

Answer (score 0):

AS `find_user['boost_time_given']` is a `datetime`, you don't want to substract a `timedelta` from it, but rather get the difference of it and `previous`. Then use `total_seconds()` to get an hour duration

```
embed.description = f"`You must wait {(find_user['boost_time_given'] - previous).total_seconds()//3600}`"
```

But to get a nice display will all units just do

```
embed.description = f"`You must wait {find_user['boost_time_given'] - previous}`"
```

Comment: Oh wow, thank you for explaining that to me. Very helpful :). Is it also possible to show the minutes, along with the hours within the same line?

Comment: @lolnooblolnooa see my edit, just keep the timedelta intact